# Duplicate a Z3Context

Tags: z3

I need to be able to duplicate a `Z3Context` instance in order to be able to add new definitions to one instance without affecting the other.

Is this possible ?

What part of the API should I look at ?

I mention that I'm using the Java API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Is no method for cloning contexts. It would also be somewhat hard to use: after cloning a context, what would be the pointers corresponding to terms and formulas in the new context? Instead there are various translation methods that let you import terms, formulas, solvers and goals between contexts. For example, use

```
       Z3_ast Z3_API Z3_translate(Z3_context source, Z3_ast a, Z3_context target);
```

to copy a term/formula between two contexts. 
The

```
     Z3_solver Z3_API Z3_solver_translate(Z3_context source, Z3_solver s, Z3_context target);
```

method lets you clone a solver. You can clone the solver between two different contexts or the same context, especially if you are just using cloning for exploring different variants of assertions.